# Storybook redux toolkit setup not working

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, storybook

Here's my .storybook/preview:

```
import { store } from "../src/app/store";

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
};
export const decorators = [
  (Story) => (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Story />
    </Provider>
  ),
];
```

I have the store working in app but I get the following error when I try to fire up storybook.

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getState')
```

What am I missing?

I've gone through this:
[How to use redux-toolkit with Storybook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67376713/how-to-use-redux-toolkit-with-storybook)

Comment: The first thing to check is that you are importing the `store` variable properly.  Any chance it’s a `default` export rather than a named export?  It might be as simple as changing `import { store }` to `import store`.  Circular import dependencies can also cause `undefined` variables.   Try `console.log(store)` and see if it’s `undefined` or not.  The error message implies that your `Provider` is working but the `store` variable is empty.

Comment: The import statement is correct, I am also exporting the persistor from the same file, so it is a named export.